# Multilanguage descriptions of a product

Tags: product, create, edit

I have a store with 3 languages (fr, nl, uk).
When I create or edit a product I have to switch from store view if I want to edit the description in each language. Each time I get the popup window with the question "Do you want to switch"?
Is it possible to put the 3 descriptions (nl, fr and uk) in 1 tab page?
thx
gp

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a way but the way magento handles saving I don't see an easy way.

I would think about using importExport to export the stuff, update it and reimport it afterwards.

If you want to make it more comfortable you can think about the paid service [cobby](https://www.cobby.io/en/) which does all the transfering for you.